# non-capturing group still shows?

Tags: java, regex, url

I am trying to get the string starting from third `/` in a url.

here is the url:

`http://192.168.1.253:18888/2021/03/11/896459e4-875f-455a-a2cb-768c879555e7.png`

I wish to get `/2021/03/11/896459e4-875f-455a-a2cb-768c879555e7.png`

So I used the following regex `(?:\/\/.+)\/.+`

`?:` marks a non-capturing group, so `//192.168.1.253:18888` shouldn't be matched.

But when I test in regex101.com, its result is `//192.168.1.254:18888/2021/03/11/896459e4-875f-455a-a2cb-768c879555e7.png`.

Why is that?

Comment: Non-capturing groups consume the text they match, they are not lookbehinds. You need `(?<!\/)\/[^\/].*` or something like that. Better, use a URL parsing feature in your language.

Comment: Please add your programming language to the tags - Regex changes per language.

Comment: You can match the `http://` up till the first `/` and capture the rest `http://[^/]+(.+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the regex101.com result is `//192.168.1.254:18888/2021/03/11/896459e4-875f-455a-a2cb-768c879555e7.png` is that non-capturing groups `(?: ... )` consume the text that they match with. Hence, where it has matched text Regex101 is showing that as a match.

For languages such as Java just match everything that doesn't include a forward slash after the initial double slash, and only keep the group match:

```
Regex: `\/\/[^\/]+(.+)`
Input: `http://192.168.1.253:18888/2021/03/11/896459e4-875f-455a-a2cb-768c879555e7.png`
Ignore Match1: `//192.168.1.253:18888/2021/03/11/896459e4-875f-455a-a2cb-768c879555e7.png`
Keep Group1: `/2021/03/11/896459e4-875f-455a-a2cb-768c879555e7.png`
```

Comment: I am familiar with Java, but is there a global solution for using non-capturing groups? It is painful that we have to learn again for each language, like SQL

Comment: The second code block should be somewhat appropriate for most languages, but unfortunately every programming language has a different implementation of Regex so it's unlikely all languages will accept the same solution.